# How do I keep navigation dropdown menus to stay open while hovering?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, navigation, navbar

I'm working on a navigation bar that I want to be responsive and have drop-downs that open and hold until I stop hovering over them. When I hover over the nav list item it displays its corresponding drop-down however I cannot seem to get it to stay in display. Below is the code I am working with:

```js
(function($) { 
  $(function() { 

    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').hover(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();

    $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
       e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });

    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();
    });

    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  }); 
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">

        <li>
          <a href="#!">About Us</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">History</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Our Staff</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Partners & Affiliates</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#!">Board of Directors</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#!">Programs</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Admissions</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Core Programs</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Alumni Success</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#!">Support Us</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Donate</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Volunteer</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Partnership</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made something that looks correct, using the `mouseenter` event to trigger the sub-nav show...
And `.show()` instead of `.toggle()`.

```js
(function($) { 
  $(function() { 

    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').on("mouseenter",function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').show();

      $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
       e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });

    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();
    });

    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  }); 
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">

        <li>
          <a href="#!">About Us</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">History</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Our Staff</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Partners & Affiliates</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#!">Board of Directors</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#!">Programs</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Admissions</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Core Programs</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Alumni Success</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#!">Support Us</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Donate</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Volunteer</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Partnership</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
```